# How do I make file with variables of all project's colors

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I use React.JS to develop a web.I want to define all the colors in one class.

In fact, I am a beginner and I only use colors at CSS files. like this:

```
.toolbar {
    background: primary1;
}
```

I also want to use them in other type classes that may be needed.

Thank you.
Also, sorry about my English.

Comment: Read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help. As far as I've found, I can only use this type variables in CSS files. Need to worry about using colors in other type classes?

Comment: You can use any CSS property this way as far as I know, sorry for the delay, was on vacation. Hope you got it figgured out.

Comment: Yeh, I did. Thanks a lot. That's really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

in Sass, you can declare all your colors in one file:

```
//colors.scss
$red: #990000;
$black: #000000;
$white: #ffffff;
```

And then in any other scss file in your project you can import and use any of the declared colors like this:

```
//style.scss
@import "path/to/colors.scss";

div {
  background: $red;
  color: $black;
}
```

You probably have sass build in support inside your react project, but if not, refer to the docs: https://sass-lang.com/documentation